# Action link to absolute url (remove the ?) and keep the parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

i'm trying to get an absolute url after sending a parameters from action link and I need it to be like

`http://MySite/Controller/View/CityName`

so I will be able to preform a search on the results page and no losing the first parameter (e.g.)

`http://MySite/Controller/View/NewYork?Lecture=bobdillen`

code :

```
@foreach (var city in @ViewBag.City)
{
    @Html.ActionLink((string)@city, "LectureIn", new { @city }, null)
}
```

the action(LectureIn) code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Lecture"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="searchLecture" class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="submit">  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and in the controller :

```
public ActionResult LectureIn(string search = null)
{
    // Do Staf
    return View();
}
```

I have tried to change the routes but it didn't change

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "lectureIn",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "TMaps", action = "lectureIn", City = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Try changing the "lectureIn" route to "{controller}/{action}/{city}" in stead.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't do the job:  "{controller}/{action}/{City}", =LectureIn?city=newyork

Comment: Right.. you'd also need to change your controller action to
public ActionResult LectureIn(string city, string search = null). the LectureIn action as it stands now, has the route template {controller}/LectureIn/{search}, so if you invoke Html.ActionLink as in your example, city would have to go after the '?'

Comment: I doesn't meter as long as city is an sbsolote url (www.mysity/new-york ,or what ever city from my list)